# Why would this javascript be causing browser crashes from memory usage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

It is looking like i have a major memory leak in this little bit of javascript. I'm hoping someone might be able to point me in a direction to possibly be a little more memory efficient, and not cause browser crashes.

This javascript is running on a page that is up on a system constantly.  It gets an applciation out of memory exception after about a week of continuous running.

Any suggestions for making this more efficient?  What part of this is causing the leak?

```
setInterval("$.get('Dashboard.aspx', function (data)
                                     {
                                         $('#buildMonitorBody').html(data);
                                     });"
            , 300000);
```

As always, I appreciate any help that can be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, web pages are not meant to stay open permanently - for such thing you have background processes or windows services.

If you do have to stick with this wrong approach, my tip would be to force reload every day with such code:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
   document.location.href = document.location.href;
}, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
```

Hopefully reloading the page will release the memory reserved for the numerous timer calls.

Comment: @Maarten the OP marked this as accepted 6 days after asking so guess it did help him. If you want direct answer from him, use `@` to reach him directly.

Answer (score 1):

Passing a string to setInterval over and over is probably the cause of the memory leaks (possibly not being garbage collected). Try doing this:

```
var loadDashboard = function() {
   $('#buildMonitorBody').load('Dashboard.aspx');
};

setInterval(loadDashboard, 300000);
```

You can use `.load` to simplify your ajax request.

Comment: .load does not seem to be working.  The Dashboard.aspx file takes about 40-40 seconds to process, could that be causing load not to get called?

Comment: I did, however, break that off into it's own function using get, so i guess in a week, I'll find out if it works >.<.

Comment: Woah that's a long time. Well anyway that amount of time shouldn't cause the `.load` to not work, as the default timeout on the ajax object is 0. `$.ajaxSetup({ timeout: 0 });` just to be sure.

Comment: It is not timing out, it will just start to transfer data, and then stop, without filling the div with the html from the Dashboard page.

Comment: Even with that change, about 4mb is being leaked on every setInterval iteration >.<.  Any other suggestions?